# HTML Email Fonts Not Scaling in Mail App on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, html-email

I need to create an email template. My email template MUST work in GMail and the mail app on iPhone. I had the template working properly in the mail app on iPhone with Zurb Ink. However, Gmail doesn't support the `style` tag in HTML emails. For that reason, I removed that framework and started from scratch. Now, the email template works fine in GMail, but the text doesn't scale up in the mail app on the iPhone. The text is all scrunched together. Currently, my HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height:100%;" height="100%">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Welcome.</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:silver; color: #2D2D2D; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial; font-weight: normal; padding:0; margin: 0; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3; width:100%; height:100%; min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; ">
  <table style="border:solid 0px #fff; width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" style="width: 100%;">
        <center>
          <table style="width:600px; border:solid 0px #fff; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
              <td align="right" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle;">
                <span style="color: #898989; font-size:12px;">Trouble viewing email? <a href="#" style="color: #6B6B6D; text-decoration:underline;">view it in your browser</a></span>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td style="height:77px; vertical-align: middle; padding-left:35px; background-color:#fff; border-left: solid 1px #D6D6D6; border-right:solid 1px #D6D6D6;">
                <img alt="Welcome." src="http://dummyimage.com/126x36/d907d9/fff.png&text=Hello" height="36" width="126" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img alt="Welcome." width="600" height="250" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x250/d907d9/fff.png&text=Welcome+to+the+new" style="display:block;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:0px 32px 36px 32px; background-color:#fff; border-top:solid 0px #fff;">
                                <div style="color:#92cc0a; padding-top:29px; font-size:36px; font-weight:lighter;">Welcome.</div>
                                <div style="padding-top:15px; font-size:14px; color:#363636;">
                                    Thanks for downloading our app. Prepare to experience a new world of imagination. Check us out on <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://www.facebook.com/myApp" target="_blank">Facebook</a>, <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://twitter.com/myApp" target="_blank">Twitter</a>, and <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://plus.google.com/+myApp/posts" target="_blank">Google +</a> for the latest details. Oh, and tell your friends!
                                </div>

                                <br />
                                Thank You
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Why isn't the text scaling properly on the mail app on the iPhone. I've included the viewport details. I've included the webkit-text-adjust stuff. Can someone please help me out?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, can you explain better the problem, cause the only difference in my iphone with gmail app is that "Thank you" does not have the same style as the above div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't actually rely on styles getting inherited, which means you will have to apply every single style to every single element all the time...
This means the font-size on the div won't actually have any effect on the text within it.

For a quick fix I suggest wrapping the text in a paragraph and applying the needed styles to it.

```
<div style="padding-top:15px; font-size:12px; color:#363636;">
  <p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial; font-weight: normal; font-size: 26px; line-height: 36px;">Thanks for downloading our app. Prepare to experience a new world of imagination. Check us out on <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://www.facebook.com/myApp" target="_blank">Facebook</a>, <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://twitter.com/myApp" target="_blank">Twitter</a>, and <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://plus.google.com/+myApp/posts" target="_blank">Google +</a> for the latest details. Oh, and tell your friends!</p>
</div>
```

Generally I would advise writing the styles in a style tag and then using a service like http://inliner.cm when you're finished and ready to inline the styles for gmail support. That way you won't have to copy&paste the font-family and default styles everywhere yourself

Using the suggested method of styling your html email in a `<style>` tag in the head and then using an inliner, you can actually go back to using the ink framework too and still have it work in gmail.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `<style>` tag:

`body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}`

The width/padding/margin/ms-text is is obviously unrelated, but should also be there.

Also, iPhone uses webkit to render, so you should be able to override the styling manually by adding a class in the `<style>` tag. Gmail will ignore this of course.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this approach and unfortunately, it did not work. The text of the email on iPhone still appeared tiny and unscaled. I reviewed the information in your style tag. However, I do not see how it differs from what I've defined inline. With the exception of the !important attribute on the width. Even after adding that, the text still did not scale properly. Thank you for your response though. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You're right - sorry, I missed what you had in your body tag. Not sure what you mean by scrunched together in your OP. Is it just rendering smaller than in Gmail? It might be the `<div>`'s, but I doubt it as it is for the Mac. Just to rule out, try wrapping your text like this `<font style="font-size:14px;">text</font>` Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

If I remember correctly, iPhones auto scale email content unless otherwise told not to by adding `initial-scale=1.0`

Hope that helps.  I know very well how frustrating email development can be.

Comment: Thank you for trying. Unfortunately, that didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Hey mate I didnt see your code but recently I fixed my newsletter by adding

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
```

in your td style

I had the same problem.

Try it might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this week and tried out a lot of code. The only solution that worked was adding this line to your `<style>`:

```
<style>
    body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
</style>
```